# Not able to install mediapipe package

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

So lately I have been trying to install the package `mediapipe` for one of my opencv projects. But when I'm trying to install it shows me this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

```
python version == 3.7.4
pip version == 19.3.0
```

one more thing when I'm trying to install it outside the venv it is installing perfectly.

Comment: Why don't you create a new venv and let mediapipe install it's requirements, see https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/python.html#ready-to-use-python-solutions?

Comment: tried doing that but no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. I was using a `32 bit` interpreter, you can verify this since it is showing `Python37-32` which means a 32 bit interpreter
[image]

so you just need to change to a `64 bit` python interpreter and also make sure that your python version is at least `3.7`